# Position of two closest points on the lines

Tags: python, geometry, line

I have found algorithm to calculate shortest distance between two lines in 3D and rewrite it in Python.But also I would like to enchanced it that it could return not only distance,but also the postion of closest points.

```
def line2line(-0.073455669 4.9843092 0.26107353 0.0 0.0 -1.0 -3.85838175 12.1999998 -4.50372314 0.405142069 -0.76723671 0.497199893):
    epsilon = 0.00000001
    L1P0 = np.array([xbeam,ybeam,zbeam]) #position of P0 on first line
    L2P0= np.array([xout,yout,zout]) #position of P0 on first line
    L1P1 = np.array([xbeam + ubeam ,ybeam + vbeam ,zbeam + wbeam]) #ubeam,vbeam and wbeam are direction cosines
    L2P1 = np.array([xout + cx,yout + cy,zout + cz]) #cx,cy,cz are direction cosines
    u = L1P1 - L1P0
    v = L2P1 - L2P0
    w = L1P0 - L2P0
    a = np.dot(u,u)
    b = np.dot(u,v)
    c = np.dot(v,v)
    d = np.dot(u,w)
    e = np.dot(v,w)
    D = a*c - b*b
    if D < epsilon:
        sc = 0.0
        tc = d/b if b>c else e/c
    else:
        sc = (b*e - c*d) / D
        tc = (a*e - b*d) / D
    dP = w + (sc * u) - (tc * v)
    return np.linalg.norm(dP)
```

It returns around 0.049 which is correct but when I tried to print 
    w + (sc * u) or 
    (tc * v) what I was thinking it was position,it printed me:

```
0.        ,   0.        , -19.82274615
3.8142822 , -7.22328672,  4.68097699
```

It's not correct.Coordinates I'm looking for for one of these points are:

```
-0.073455669 4.9843092 0.26107353
```

Algorithm I have found [here](http://geomalgorithms.com/a07-_distance.html#dist3D_Line_to_Line())

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  "I can't figure out" is not a problem specification.  What *do* you get from this algorithm?  How did you *not* find a solution on line?  This is a known solved problem.

Comment: Does adding a sample arguments and results will make it MCVE? If so,I can change it,if it makes it more usefull for StackOverflow community.
And even it is known solved problem I couldn't find sufficent solution using internet.How excatly am I supouse to explain how did I didn't find something?

Comment: Sample arguments, results, and your analysis of *trying* to find the points would help a lot.  Also, you might include a link to the algorithm you implemented.

Comment: I have included direct lint to the algorithm.It is right under the code.

Comment: @Ajean: no, OP has the algorithm for shortest *distance*.  This algorithm does not find the points at that closest approach.

Comment: @wiedzminYo -- My apology; I missed the link the first time.  I also got a lot of good hits with the search "shortest path between skew lines".

Comment: Also, I've retracted my close vote and up-voted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dP` is difference vector. But you need absolute coordinates of the closest points

I cannot open linked page, but seems that `sc` is parameter for the first line parametric equation and `tc` is parameter for the second line. In this case

```
ClosestPointAtFirst = L1P0 + sc * u
ClosestPointAtSecond = L2P0 + tc * v
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the approach.

The algorithm *does* find the unit vector normal to both lines.  You also know the distance.  That gives you the vector of the line segment connecting the two points of interest.

Apply that vector as a linear transformation to `u`.  This gives you a new line, `u-prime`, which is shifted in the direction of the normal vector, by a distance you've computed.  `u-prime` will intersect `v` at one of the two points.  Find that intersection (which is the point on `v` of closest approach), subtract the connecting vector, and that gives your other point (on the original `u`).

If it helps to visualize, not that `u-prime` and `v` define a plane that is perpendicular to the normal vector.